# Random generator unexpected behavior

Tags: haskell, random

I'm working with the `System.Random` library and I've come across some behavior that I don't fully understand. The `shuffle` function below is an implementation of the [Fischer-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) that also works as a random sample without replacement. E.g. calling `shuffle` with a list and the length of the list will shuffle the whole list, but calling it with a list and the number 2 should extract a random sample of length 2.

```
import           Control.Monad               as M
import           Control.Monad.ST
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM
import           System.Random

go = do
  g <- newStdGen
  let (rand_vec1, g1) = randVector 10 g
  let (rand_vec2, g2) = randVector 10 g
  let (rand_sample1, g3) = shuffle rand_vec1 2 g
  let (rand_sample2, g4) = shuffle rand_vec1 2 g
  print rand_vec1
  print rand_vec2
  print rand_sample1
  print rand_sample2

randVector :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> g -> (VU.Vector Int, g)
randVector n = shuffle vector (VU.length vector) where
  vector = VU.enumFromN 0 n

shuffle :: (RandomGen g, Unbox a) => VU.Vector a -> Int -> g -> (VU.Vector a, g)
shuffle li size g = runST $ do
  vector <- VU.unsafeThaw li
  let n = VUM.length vector - 1
  let step g i = do
              let (j,g') = randomR (0,n) g
              VUM.swap vector i j
              return g'
  g' <- M.foldM step g [0..size-1]
  v' <- VU.unsafeFreeze vector
  let vec = VU.take size v'
  return (vec, g')
```

I notice that `rand_vec1` and `rand_vec2` are always identical, which is to be expected, since the same random number generator is used.

However, `rand_sample1` and `rand_sample2` differs even though they both use the same random generator. Even stranger, more than half the time, but not always, `rand_sample2` just contains the two first numbers of the vector being sampled from (like in the example below). How come?
Example output:

> [3,0,4,9,7,2,1,8,5,6]
>
> [3,0,4,9,7,2,1,8,5,6]
>
> [9,2]
>
> [3,0]

(Also, code review is appreciated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `shuffle` is using `unsafeThaw/Freeze` it is actually modifying the input vector, i.e. `rand_vec1` in this case.

Try running this:

```
go = do
  g <- newStdGen
  let (rand_vec1, g1) = randVector 10 g
  print rand_vec1
  let (rand_vec2, g2) = randVector 10 g
  print rand_vec2
  let (rand_sample1, g3) = shuffle rand_vec1 2 g
  print rand_sample1
  print ("rand_vec1: ", rand_vec1)
  let (rand_sample2, g4) = shuffle rand_vec1 2 g
  print rand_sample2
  print ("rand_vec1: ", rand_vec1)
```

And here is the output:

```
*Main> go
[7,0,3,5,2,6,9,8,1,4]
[7,0,3,5,2,6,9,8,1,4]
[0,3]
("rand_vec1: ", [0,3,7,5,2,6,9,8,1,4])
[3,7]
("rand_vec1: ", [3,7,0,5,2,6,9,8,1,4])
```

To answer your second question, the short answer is that the vector returned by `shuffle` shares the same memory as the (modified) input vector.

Comment: I thought that any changes in `runST` could not "escape" unless explicitly returned. Should not `shuffle` have no side effects, since everything is done inside `runST`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example of what you mean by this. The problem here is that you're using unsafe operations which violate the underlying assumptions of the ST monad.

Comment: That explains it! By changing `VU.unsafeThaw` to `VU.thaw`, the random samples are equal. If I don't use any unsafe operations in `runST` then the operations should not have any side effects, right?

Comment: Also, for this particular sample, is it safe to only use the safe version `thaw` and the unsafe version of `freeze`, since the mutable vector is not returned?

Comment: Probably will work. I'm still looking for the vector equivalent to `runSTArray` to avoid copying on both the thaw and freeze operations.

Comment: Try using `create` - this should avoid a copy.

Comment: But it must be necessary to create at least one copy? If so then would not safe thaw + unsafe freeze be equivalent?

Comment: safe thaw + unsafe freeze should be fine